# After upgrade to IntelliJ 2017.1, Class JavaLaunchHelper Error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, upgrade

I just updated to IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 and now I get this error message every time on runtime:

**objc[3318]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x107a4c4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x107b144e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.**

Everything works as usual. It's just really annoying to look at. I didn't have this error message before in the older version of IntelliJ.

If there is no fix is it then possible to just tell IntelliJ to not give me this specific error when I run my programs?

Comment: As a temporary solution I downgraded to IntelliJ 2016.3.5 to fix this.

Comment: Why the question is duplicated ? The problem is different. More about intelliJ now

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43003231/104891 for the answer.