# Eclipse is not opening in Mac

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I am trying to open Eclipse through the "Open package contents". 
In the terminal after this its showing:

```
186590d10a33:~ mshikher$ /Users/mshikher/Downloads/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse ; exit;
objc[9445]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib (0x100541480) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1005a34e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ../Eclipse/lombok.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I am using jdk-8u131-macrosx-x64.
How can I open my eclipse?

Comment: This is a know error you have to upgrade your JDK search google for **Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both** to see details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003231/1167890

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the `-javaagent:../Eclipse/lombok.jar` in `eclipse.ini` file. It is in `/Users/mshikher/Downloads/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini`