# How do I avoid showing a message that debugging has started and ended in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When debugging is started `IntelliJ` shows in console that message:

> Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:18443', transport:
>   'socket'

and when debugging has finished it shows

> Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:18443',
>   transport: 'socket'

**How do I get rid of those messages?**

Comment: IntelliJ is open source, you could remove it from the source and build your own.  Or you could ignore it.

Comment: Try folding the specific lines in the output, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46318034/104891).

Comment: Why ? Debugging is a developer activity. It should have zero relevance to whatever application you are coding.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of them?

Comment: @CrazyCoder It did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: You can remove them with https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console

Comment: @Meo That's even better answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Console | **Fold console lines that contain**.

[image: fold console]

Add the debugger messages to the patterns list.

Comment: The linked page says that the setting only applies to python, but the question is about java.  For java, under Windows, the setting can currently be found at Settings -> Editor -> General -> Console.